# Using ng-init to send data from a ng-repeat to another controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-init

I have a html file that runs a `ng-repeat` and then each item in that ng-repeat will generate a template which also has it's own controller

On the html file I have something like:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <div ng-include="'template.html" ng-init="getData(item)"></div>
</div>
```

And then this template has it's own controller.

The controller has the function getData(item) and looks something like this:

```
$scope.getData = function(item){
 var chapter = item;
}

$scope.myVec = chapter.myVec.length;
```

template.html looks like:

```
<div ng-controller = "Controller">

<p>{{myVec}}</p>

</div>
```

And then I get an error on the console saying "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

What am I missing here? Is the controller running before the function that defines the `var chapter`?

Comment: instead of using `ng-include` and `ng-init` with an inner `ng-controller`, you really should consider making this a directive.  the `ng-init` won't really work here, since it is bound to the outer controller, but you want the data on the inner controller.

Comment: Yeah, I think I got it now. Running the function on ng-init will only get the data within the function's scope and not the whole controller

Comment: I wrote a quick directive that *does what I think you are trying to accomplish*;  let me know if it helps (or doesn't):  http://plnkr.co/edit/aoLzsSmmszeJiVa7znXY?p=preview

Comment: Yeah I see what you did there! Thank you, it works!
I also found another solution. I used $scope.$parent and the item that's in the parent scope. Because the controller of the template is within the other controller this solves the issue!
Thank you for your solution also!

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's because chapter is a local variable to your $scope.getData function. For example

```
function foo(num){
   var myNum=num
}
foo(3)
console.log(myNum) // your will get undefinied
```

do this instead

```
var myNum
function foo(num){
   myNum=num
}
foo(3)
console.log(myNum) // your will get 3
```

Comment: I tried declaring the variable before the function now and i still get undefined. maybe it is kind of "running" the whole code before the ng-init gets called in the html file. So he doesn't know the field myVec in the object chapter

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem is from the ng-repeat u r sending the item (which is an array element,  primitive type not an object) to the function getData().  That's why it returns cannot read property length undefined. I hope this helps you.

```
Var items = [ 'apple',  'mango'] ;
items.length //2
Items[0].length // error
```

Comment: the ng-repeat is "repeating" objects within a vector. then each object has a field that is a vector, myVec. So it should be able to get the length. this is definitely a scope issue

Comment: Can you please update your items array with some mock data?So that we can figure out the actual issue.

Comment: I took a different approach. I used $scope.$parent because the template controller is within another controller, which has the data I was passing through. This way I only pass exactly what I need